# Html.Actionlink with ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back To Blog","Blog","Home", new {Model.BlogId}, null)
```

That code is generating this HTML:

```
<a href="/Home/Blog?BlogId=1">Back To Blog</a>
```

But what I **want** it to generate is this:

```
<a href="/Home/Blog/1">Back To Blog</a>
```

How do I fix this?

PS - I saw this post on SO which seems to indicate I'm doing it the right way, but I am not getting the results I want. I am using MVC4, latest version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect you don't have a route configured for `Home/Blog/{BlogId}`. So if you want to be able to write this (as what you show in your code):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back To Blog","Blog","Home", new { Model.BlogId}, null)
```

You need to have a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultBlog",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{blogid}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Blog", 
            blogid = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Notice the third part of the url which is named `blogid`. But if you don't want to configure another route then you can just rewrite your link as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back To Blog","Blog","Home", new { id = Model.BlogId}, null)
```

Notice the `id` on the parameter.

Comment: Agreed with `new {id = Model.BlogId}`. Specifying `id` might fix it.

Comment: Specifying `id` **"will"** fix it and not just **"might"** ;)

Comment: Yup - this worked: @Html.ActionLink("Back To Blog","Blog","Home", new { id = Model.BlogId}, null)