# how to pass id into dynamic actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I am trying to paginate through book pages one page at a time. I use itextsharp to get text from a page from pdf file. the first page will be displayed by default then the user can click on a link to proceed to next page:

```
@html.ActionLink("Page","index","home",new {id=4},null)
```

I want the id value to be dynamically set: in this case each click will increase the id value by one so that the next page will be retrieved and displayed.
I also want a backward link where id will be decreased by each click.
I tried to do this in index action like so:

```
ViewBag.ID=id++
```

and then plug ViewBag.ID into

```
@html.ActionLink("Page","index","home",new {id=@ViewBag.ID},null)
```

but this did not work.

Comment: Please post your code for the Index() method

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your approach, but if `id=4` then `ViewBag.ID = id++;` will also equal 4 - `id++` is a post increment operator - it should be `ViewBag.ID = ++id;` if you want it to equal 5

Comment: you are right Stephen! however I created model book with next and previous properties; then in index action assigned id+1 and id-1 respectively to them and then in used Model.next and Model.previous in html.Actionlink("<<Prev ","home","index",new{id=Model.previous},null)

Comment: Good - using view models are much better that ViewBag

Answer (score 1):

I Suspect the problem you are facing same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915861/html-actionlink-with-id).

Also, I Hope you are looping and assigning `id` to the Link via `ViewBag.ID`. My Question is why we need `ViewBag` here. straight away you can assign. Like below...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back To Blog","Blog","Home", new { id = id}, null)
```

You can try another way of pure html with `MVC` `Url.Action`:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Blog", "Home", new { id = id })">Back To Blog</a>
```

*For Best understanding see the help text below what you are trying...*

**For Action Link :**

```
ActionLink(string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, Object routeValues, Object htmlAttributes)
```

**For Url Action :**

```
Action(string actionName, string controllerName, Object routeValues)
```